# How to create an "Expression" with babylon?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-babylon

I need to add an objectProperty, but it requires key and value:

> t.objectProperty(key, value, ...)

And the value must be an "Expression". I assumed that it must be object expression:

> t.objectExpression(properties)

Where "properties" must be an array of ObjectMethod || ObjectProperty || SpreadProperty.

But I wanted to create an ObjectProperty in the first place!
So what is an "Expression" and how can I create it in order to create an ObjectProperty?

Comment: No, the `value` part of an `objectProperty` can be an arbitrary expression, not an `objectExpression`. In fact it's the reverse, and object expression (`{…}`) contains zero or more object properties (`key:value`) or methods (`name(…){…}`) or a spread elements (`...…`).

Comment: @Bergi looks like I can't create an ObjectProperty without ObjectExpression?
O.K. but how can I create ObjectExpression?

Comment: Looks like `t.objectExpression([t.objectProperty(key, value), …])`

Comment: I mean how can I create value, that must be an Expression?

Comment: Well, what expression do you want to become the value of the property?

Comment: String literal, for example.

Comment: Then just use `value = t.stringLiteral("content")`?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), I found an answer.
An example where an object's property value is a string:

```
t.objectExpression([
  t.objectProperty(
  t.identifier('key'),
  t.stringLiteral('value'),
)]);
```